# Read array list from file text. (Loop, format for day and first/last day hot of temperature)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, simpledateformat

This is my Homework this week. 
---They need :

```
Name: Eric Hornberger
Hometown: Columbus,Nebraska
Birthdate: 18 February 1960
Location: Columbus
Date        AvgTemp MaxTemp MinTemp AvgSnow MaxSnow MinSnow AvgPrec MaxPrec MinPrec
August 2015 71.42   96      46      0.0     0.0     0.0    0.12     1.72    0.0
August 2014 76.06   96      51      0.0     0.0     0.0    0.24    2.66     0.0
August 2013 76.11   100     52      0.0     0.0     0.0    0.04    0.69     0.0
August 2012 74.45   103     44      0.0     0.0     0.0    0.01    0.13     0.0
August 2011 75.55   104     55      0.0     0.0     0.0    0.22     2.62    0.0
August 2010 78.11   100     52      0.0     0.0     0.0    0.09    0.84     0.0
August 2009 72.31   102     42      0.0     0.0     0.0    0.1      1.06    0.0
August 2008 75.42   102     50      0.0     0.0     0.0    0.06     0.46    0.0
August 2007 79.47   100     56      0.0     0.0     0.0     0.19    1.34    0.0
August 2006 75.68   105     52      0.0     0.0      0.0    0.13    1.71    0.0
For the past 10 years:
Average Temp:   75.46
Average Snow:   0.0
Average Precip: 0.12
Hottest August: 2006
Year    FirstHotDay     LastHotDay
2015    -       -
2014    -           -
2013    30 August   30 August
2012    01 August   30 August
2011    01 August   01 August
2010    12 August   12 August
2009    08 August   08 August
2008    03 August   03 August
2007    13 August   13 August
2006    01 August   09 August
```

This is my work, and I am stuck right now, please help me. I don't know how to change the day in file .txt "20150822". My output shows the wrong number. 
How can I find FirstHotDay and LastHotDay.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class ClimateSummary {


    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("dataB.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        String firstN = scan.next();
        String lastN = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Name: " + firstN + (" ") + lastN);

    String city = scan.next();
    String state = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Hometown: " + city + (" ") + state);

    String day = scan.next();
    String month = scan.next();
    String year = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Birthdate: " + day + (" ") + month + (" ") + year);

    String location = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Location: " + location);

    System.out.println("Date" + "           " + "AvgTemp"
            +"  " + "MaxTemp" + "  " + "MinTemp" + "  " + "AvgSnow"
            + "  " + "MaxSnow" + "  " + "MinSnow" + "  "
            + "AvgPrec" + "  " + "MaxPrec" + "  " + "MinPrec");


    int[] stationNum = new int[310];
    String[] dataYear = new String[310];
    int[] highTemp = new int[310];
    int[] lowTemp = new int[310];
    int[] snowFall = new int[310];
    double[] prec = new double[310];


    double[] highLowTemp = new double[310];
    double totalTemp15 = 0.0;
    double totalTemp14 = 0.0;
    double totalTemp13 = 0.0;
    double totalTemp12 = 0.0;
    double totalTemp11 = 0.0;
    double totalTemp10 = 0.0;
    double totalTemp9 = 0.0;
    double totalTemp8 = 0.0;
    double totalTemp7 = 0.0;
    double totalTemp6 = 0.0;
String y2015;
int highestT15 = 0;
int lowestT15 = 0;
double avgsnow15 = 0.0;
double avgpre2015 = 0.0;
double avgT15 = 0.0;

 int i;
    for(i = 0; i < stationNum.length ;++i){
    stationNum[i] = scan.nextInt();
    dataYear[i] = scan.next();
    highTemp[i] = scan.nextInt();
    lowTemp[i] = scan.nextInt();
    snowFall[i] = scan.nextInt();
    prec[i] = scan.nextDouble();
    //2015
    if(i < 31) {
        y2015 = dataYear[i];
        totalTemp15 += (highTemp[i] + lowTemp[i]); 
        avgT15 +=totalTemp15;
        avgT15 /= (highTemp.length + lowTemp.length) * 1.0;
        if(totalTemp15 > highestT15)
        {
            totalTemp15 = highestT15;
            }
        if(totalTemp15 < lowestT15)
        {
            totalTemp15 = lowestT15;        
            }
        double maxSnow15 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] > maxSnow15 ){ 
            maxSnow15 = snowFall[i];
        }
        double minSnow15 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] < minSnow15){
            minSnow15 = snowFall[i];

        avgsnow15 += snowFall[i];
        avgsnow15 += snowFall.length * 1.0;
        }
        double maxPr15 = 0.0;
        if (prec[i] > maxPr15 ){
            maxPr15 = prec[i];}
        double minPr15 = 0.0;
        if(prec[i] < minPr15 ) { 
            minPr15 = prec[i];

        avgpre2015 += prec[i];
        avgpre2015 += prec.length * 1.0;

    System.out.println(y2015 + "   " + avgT15 + " "+ highestT15 + "    "+lowestT15 +"    " + avgsnow15 + "    " 
        +maxSnow15 + "    " + minSnow15 + "    "+ avgpre2015 + "    " + maxPr15 + "    " + minPr15 );
        }
    //2014
    else if (i > 30 && i < 62) {
        String y2014 = dataYear[i];
        totalTemp14 += (highTemp[i] + lowTemp[i]); 
        double avgT14 = totalTemp14;
        avgT14 /= (highTemp.length + lowTemp.length) * 1.0;
        double highestT14 = 0.0;
        double lowestT14 = 0.0;
        if(totalTemp14 > highestT14)
        {
            totalTemp14 = highestT14;
            }
        if(totalTemp14 < lowestT14)
        {
            totalTemp14 = lowestT14;        
            }
        double maxSnow14 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] > maxSnow14 ){ 
            maxSnow14 = snowFall[i];
        }
        double minSnow14 = 0.0;
        double avgsnow14 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] < minSnow14){
            minSnow14 = snowFall[i];

        avgsnow14 += snowFall[i];
        avgsnow14 += snowFall.length * 1.0;

        double maxPr14 = 0.0;
        if (prec[i] > maxPr14 ){
            maxPr14 = prec[i];}
        double minPr14 = 0.0;
        if(prec[i] < minPr14 ) { 
            minPr14 = prec[i];
            double avgpre2014 = 0.0;
        avgpre2014 += prec[i];
        avgpre2014 += prec.length * 1.0;

    System.out.println(y2014 + "   " + avgT14 + " "+ highestT14 + "    "+lowestT14 +"    " + avgsnow14 + "    " 
        +maxSnow14 + "    " + minSnow14 + "    "+ avgpre2014 + "    " + maxPr14 + "    " + minPr14 );
        }
    //2013
    else if (i > 61 && i < 93) {
        String y2013 = dataYear[i];
        totalTemp13 += (highTemp[i] + lowTemp[i]); 
        double avgT13 = totalTemp13;
        avgT13 /= (highTemp.length + lowTemp.length) * 1.0;
        double highestT13 =0.0;
        double lowestT13=0.0;
        if(totalTemp13 > highestT13){
            totalTemp13 = highestT13;}
        if(totalTemp13 < lowestT13){
            totalTemp13 = lowestT13;        }
        double maxSnow13 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] > maxSnow13 ){ 
            maxSnow13 = snowFall[i];
        }
        double minSnow13 = 0.0;
        double avgsnow13 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] < minSnow13){
            minSnow13 = snowFall[i];

        avgsnow13 += snowFall[i];
        avgsnow13 += snowFall.length * 1.0;

        double maxPr13 = 0.0;
        if (prec[i] > maxPr14 ){
            maxPr13 = prec[i];}
        double minPr13 = 0.0;
        if(prec[i] < minPr13 ) { 
            minPr13 = prec[i];
            double avgpre2013 = 0.0;
        avgpre2013 += prec[i];
        avgpre2013 += prec.length * 1.0;

    System.out.println(y2013 + "   " + avgT13 + " "+ highestT13 + "    "+lowestT13 +"    " + avgsnow13 + "    " 
        +maxSnow13 + "    " + minSnow13 + "    "+ avgpre2013 + "    " + maxPr13 + "    " + minPr13 );
        }
    //2012
    else if (i > 92 && i < 124) {
        String y2012 = dataYear[i];
        totalTemp12 += (highTemp[i] + lowTemp[i]); 
        double avgT12 = totalTemp12;
        avgT12 /= (highTemp.length + lowTemp.length) * 1.0;
        double highestT12 = 0.0;
        double lowestT12 = 0.0;
        if(totalTemp12 > highestT12)
        {
            totalTemp12 = highestT12;
            }
        if(totalTemp12 < lowestT12)

        {
            totalTemp12 = lowestT12;        }
        double maxSnow12 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] > maxSnow12 ){ 
            maxSnow12 = snowFall[i];
        }
        double minSnow12 = 0.0;
        double avgsnow12 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] < minSnow12){
            minSnow12 = snowFall[i];

        avgsnow12 += snowFall[i];
        avgsnow12 += snowFall.length * 1.0;
        }
        double maxPr12 = 0.0;
        if (prec[i] > maxPr12 ){
            maxPr14 = prec[i];}
        double minPr12 = 0.0;
        if(prec[i] < minPr12 ) { 
            minPr12 = prec[i];
            double avgpre2012 = 0.0;
        avgpre2012 += prec[i];
        avgpre2012 += prec.length * 1.0;

    System.out.println(y2012 + "   " + avgT12 + " "+ highestT12 + "    "+lowestT12 +"    " + avgsnow12 + "    " 
        +maxSnow12 + "    " + minSnow12 + "    "+ avgpre2012 + "    " + maxPr12 + "    " + minPr12 );
        }
    //2011
    else if (i > 123 && i < 155) {
        String y2011 = dataYear[i];
        totalTemp11 += (highTemp[i] + lowTemp[i]); 
        double avgT11 = totalTemp11;
        avgT11 /= (highTemp.length + lowTemp.length) * 1.0;
        double highestT11 = 0.0;
        double lowestT11 = 0.0;
        if(totalTemp11 > highestT11)
        {
            totalTemp11 = highestT11;
            }
        if(totalTemp11 < lowestT11){
            totalTemp11 = lowestT11;
            }
        double maxSnow11 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] > maxSnow11 ){ 
            maxSnow11 = snowFall[i];
        }
        double minSnow11 = 0.0;
        double avgsnow11 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] < minSnow11){
            minSnow11 = snowFall[i];

        avgsnow11 += snowFall[i];
        avgsnow11 += snowFall.length * 1.0;
        }
        double maxPr11 = 0.0;
        if (prec[i] > maxPr11 ){
            maxPr11 = prec[i];}
        double minPr11 = 0.0;
        if(prec[i] < minPr11 ) { 
            minPr11 = prec[i];
            double avgpre2011 = 0.0;
        avgpre2011 += prec[i];
        avgpre2011 += prec.length * 1.0;

    System.out.println(y2011 + "   " + avgT11 + " "+ highestT11 + "    "+lowestT11 +"    " + avgsnow11 + "    " 
        +maxSnow11 + "    " + minSnow11 + "    "+ avgpre2011 + "    " + maxPr11 + "    " + minPr11 );
        }
    //2010
    else if (i > 154 && i < 186) {
            String y2010 = dataYear[i];
            totalTemp10 += (highTemp[i] + lowTemp[i]); 
            double avgT10 = totalTemp10;
            avgT10 /= (highTemp.length + lowTemp.length) * 1.0;
            double highestT10 = 0.0;
            double lowestT10 = 0.0;
            if(totalTemp10 > highestT10){
                totalTemp10 = highestT10;}
            if(totalTemp10 < lowestT10){
                totalTemp10 = lowestT10;
                }
            double maxSnow10 = 0.0;
            if(snowFall[i] > maxSnow10 ){ 
                maxSnow10 = snowFall[i];
            }
            double minSnow10 = 0.0;
            double avgsnow10 = 0.0;
            if(snowFall[i] < minSnow10){
                minSnow10 = snowFall[i];

            avgsnow10 += snowFall[i];
            avgsnow10 += snowFall.length * 1.0;
            }
            double maxPr10 = 0.0;
            if (prec[i] > maxPr10 ){
                maxPr10 = prec[i];}
            double minPr10 = 0.0;
            if(prec[i] < minPr10 ) { 
                minPr10 = prec[i];
                double avgpre2010 = 0.0;
            avgpre2010 += prec[i];
            avgpre2010 += prec.length * 1.0;

        System.out.println(y2010 + "   " + avgT10 + " "+ highestT10 + "    "+lowestT10 +"    " + avgsnow10 + "    " 
            +maxSnow10 + "    " + minSnow10 + "    "+ avgpre2010 + "    " + maxPr10 + "    " + minPr10 );
            }
    //2009
    else if (i > 185 && i < 217) {
        String y2009 = dataYear[i];
        totalTemp9 += (highTemp[i] + lowTemp[i]); 
        double avgT9 = totalTemp9;
        avgT9 /= (highTemp.length + lowTemp.length) * 1.0;
        double highestT9 = 0.0;
        double lowestT9 = 0.0;
        if(totalTemp9 > highestT9){
            totalTemp9 = highestT9;}
        if(totalTemp9 < lowestT9){
            totalTemp9 = lowestT9;
            }
        double maxSnow9 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] > maxSnow9 ){ 
            maxSnow9 = snowFall[i];
        }
        double minSnow9 = 0.0;
        double avgsnow9 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] < minSnow9){
            minSnow9 = snowFall[i];
        avgsnow9 += snowFall[i];
        avgsnow9 += snowFall.length * 1.0;
        }
        double maxPr9 = 0.0;
        if (prec[i] > maxPr9 ){
            maxPr9 = prec[i];}
        double minPr9 = 0.0;
        if(prec[i] < minPr9 ) { 
            minPr9 = prec[i];
            double avgpre2009 = 0.0;
        avgpre2009 += prec[i];
        avgpre2009 += prec.length * 1.0;

    System.out.println(y2009 + "   " + avgT9 + " "+ highestT9 + "    "+lowestT9 +"    " + avgsnow9 + "    " 
        +maxSnow9 + "    " + minSnow9 + "    "+ avgpre2009 + "    " + maxPr9 + "    " + minPr9 );
        }
    //2008
    else if (i > 216 && i < 248) {
        String y2008 = dataYear[i];
        totalTemp8 += (highTemp[i] + lowTemp[i]); 
        double avgT8 = totalTemp8;
        avgT8 /= (highTemp.length + lowTemp.length) * 1.0;
        double highestT8 = 0.0;
        double lowestT8 = 0.0;
        if(totalTemp8 > highestT8){
            totalTemp8 = highestT8;}
        if(totalTemp8 < lowestT8){
            totalTemp8 = lowestT8;      
            }
        double maxSnow8 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] > maxSnow8 ){ 
            maxSnow8 = snowFall[i];
        }
        double minSnow8 = 0.0;
        double avgsnow8 = 0.0;
        if(snowFall[i] < minSnow8){
            minSnow8 = snowFall[i];

        avgsnow8 += snowFall[i];
        avgsnow8 += snowFall.length * 1.0;
        }
        double maxPr8 = 0.0;
        if (prec[i] > maxPr8 ){
            maxPr8 = prec[i];}
        double minPr8 = 0.0;
        if(prec[i] < minPr8 ) { 
            minPr8 = prec[i];
            double avgpre2008 = 0.0;
        avgpre2008 += prec[i];
        avgpre2008 += prec.length * 1.0;

    System.out.println(y2008 + "   " + avgT8 + " "+ highestT8 + "    "+lowestT8 +"    " + avgsnow8 + "    " 
        +maxSnow8 + "    " + minSnow8 + "    "+ avgpre2008 + "    " + maxPr8 + "    " + minPr8 );
        }

    //2007
    else if (i > 247 && i < 279) {
            String y2007 = dataYear[i];
            totalTemp7 += (highTemp[i] + lowTemp[i]); 
            double avgT7 = totalTemp7;
            avgT7 /= (highTemp.length + lowTemp.length) * 1.0;
            double highestT7 = 0.0;
            double lowestT7 = 0.0;
            if(totalTemp7 > highestT7){
                totalTemp7 = highestT7;}
            if(totalTemp7 < lowestT7)   {
                totalTemp7 = lowestT7;      
                }
            double maxSnow7 = 0.0;
            if(snowFall[i] > maxSnow7 ){ 
                maxSnow7 = snowFall[i];
            }
            double minSnow7 = 0.0;
            double avgsnow7 = 0.0;
            if(snowFall[i] < minSnow7){
                minSnow7 = snowFall[i];

            avgsnow7 += snowFall[i];
            avgsnow7 += snowFall.length * 1.0;
            }
            double maxPr7 = 0.0;
            if (prec[i] > maxPr7 ){
                maxPr9 = prec[i];}
            double minPr7 = 0.0;
            if(prec[i] < minPr7 ) { 
                minPr7 = prec[i];
                double avgpre2007 = 0.0;
            avgpre2007 += prec[i];
            avgpre2007 += prec.length * 1.0;

        System.out.println(y2007 + "   " + avgT7 + " "+ highestT7 + "    "+lowestT7 +"    " + avgsnow7 + "    " 
            +maxSnow7 + "    " + minSnow7 + "    "+ avgpre2007 + "    " + maxPr7 + "    " + minPr7 );}


    // 2006
        else if (i > 278) {
            String y2006 = dataYear[i];
            totalTemp6 += (highTemp[i] + lowTemp[i]); 
                double avgT6 = totalTemp6;
                avgT6 /= (highTemp.length + lowTemp.length) * 1.0;
                double highestT6 = 0.0;
                double lowestT6 = 0.0;
                if(totalTemp6 > highestT6){
                    totalTemp6 = highestT6;
                if(totalTemp6 < lowestT6){
                    totalTemp6 = lowestT6;  
                    }
                double maxSnow6 = 0.0;
                if(snowFall[i] > maxSnow6 ){ 
                    maxSnow9 = snowFall[i];
                }
                double minSnow6 = 0.0;
                double avgsnow6 = 0.0;
                if(snowFall[i] < minSnow6){
                    minSnow6= snowFall[i];

                avgsnow6 += snowFall[i];
                avgsnow6 += snowFall.length * 1.0;

                double maxPr6 = 0.0;
                if (prec[i] > maxPr6 ){
                    maxPr6 = prec[i];}
                double minPr6 = 0.0;
                if(prec[i] < minPr6 ) { 
                    minPr6 = prec[i];}
                    double avgpre2006 = 0.0;
                avgpre2006 += prec[i];
                avgpre2006 += prec.length * 1.0;

            System.out.println(y2006 + "   " + avgT6 + " "+ highestT6 + "    "+lowestT6 +"    " + avgsnow6 + "    " 
                +maxSnow6 + "    " + minSnow6 + "    "+ avgpre2006 + "    " + maxPr6 + "    " + minPr6 );

    // Past 10 years
            System.out.println("For the past 10 year:");

            double avgTemp = (avgT15+avgT14+avgT13+avgT12+
                    avgT11+avgT10+avgT9+avgT8+avgT7+avgT6)/10;
            System.out.println("Average Temp:    " + avgTemp);  

            double avgSnow = (avgsnow15+avgsnow14+avgsnow13+avgsnow12+avgsnow11+avgsnow10
                    +avgsnow9+avgsnow8+avgsnow7+avgsnow6) /10;
            System.out.println("Average Snow:    " + avgSnow);

            double avgPrec = (avgpre2015+avgpre2014+avgpre2013+avgpre2012+avgpre2011
                    +avgpre2010+avgpre2009+avgpre2008+avgpre2007+avgpre2006) / 10;
            System.out.println("Average Precip:    " + avgPrec);

            if(i < highTemp.length){
                ++i; 
                while()

            }


    }}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

This is data file: 
Name
Place of birth
Birth date
Place collect of data
stationumber, YearMonthDay, high temp., low temp.,snowfall,Precip.

```
John Fischer
Denver, Colorado
3 February 1980
Chicago
14939   20150801    89  63  0   0
14939   20150802    96  71  0   0
14939   20150803    86  67  0   0
14939   20150804    89  67  0   0.17
14939   20150805    83  70  0   0
14939   20150806    82  63  0   0.03
14939   20150807    93  67  0   0
14939   20150808    88  69  0   0.36
14939   20150809    89  74  0   0
14939   20150810    85  63  0   0
14939   20150811    87  58  0   0
14939   20150812    88  59  0   0
14939   20150813    90  62  0   0
14939   20150814    92  68  0   0
14939   20150815    92  64  0   0
14939   20150816    94  69  0   0
14939   20150817    78  68  0   1.72
14939   20150818    75  56  0   0.36
14939   20150819    77  53  0   0.08
14939   20150820    85  52  0   0
14939   20150821    86  64  0   0
14939   20150822    91  65  0   0.01    
14939   20150823    76  50  0   0
14939   20150824    82  46  0   0
14939   20150825    82  51  0   0
14939   20150826    85  55  0   0
14939   20150827    87  66  0   0.31
14939   20150828    80  64  0   0.74
14939   20150829    74  61  0   0
14939   20150830    78  62  0   0
14939   20150831    88  62  0   0
14939   20140801    86  63  0   0
14939   20140802    90  59  0   0.06
14939   20140803    93  66  0   0
14939   20140804    87  64  0   0
14939   20140805    93  67  0   0
14939   20140806    83  71  0   0.21
14939   20140807    81  68  0   0
14939   20140808    83  70  0   0
14939   20140809    85  68  0   0.55
14939   20140810    85  68  0   0.08
14939   20140811    80  57  0   0
14939   20140812    81  51  0   0
14939   20140813    87  53  0   0
14939   20140814    89  57  0   0
14939   20140815    76  69  0   0.23
14939   20140816    87  69  0   0
14939   20140817    92  67  0   0.31
14939   20140818    91  62  0   0.01
14939   20140819    93  66  0   0
14939   20140820    96  74  0   0
14939   20140821    90  71  0   0.23
14939   20140822    93  73  0   0.18
14939   20140823    95  69  0   0.21
14939   20140824    91  70  0   0
14939   20140825    83  64  0   0
14939   20140826    81  63  0   1.45
14939   20140827    77  67  0   0.65
14939   20140828    82  69  0   2.66
14939   20140829    75  67  0   0
14939   20140830    87  64  0   0
14939   20140831    92  66  0   0.71
14939   20130801    89  62  0   0.69
14939   20130802    84  65  0   0.06
14939   20130803    80  62  0   0
14939   20130804    79  61  0   0
14939   20130805    86  70  0   0
14939   20130806    88  67  0   0
14939   20130807    85  66  0   0
14939   20130808    79  65  0   0
14939   20130809    83  60  0   0
14939   20130810    84  54  0   0
14939   20130811    87  61  0   0.01
14939   20130812    85  65  0   0.09
14939   20130813    80  60  0   0
14939   20130814    78  56  0   0
14939   20130815    70  63  0   0.25
14939   20130816    75  62  0   0
14939   20130817    80  60  0   0
14939   20130818    81  52  0   0
14939   20130819    87  63  0   0
14939   20130820    91  70  0   0
14939   20130821    92  69  0   0
14939   20130822    86  68  0   0.01
14939   20130823    92  71  0   0
14939   20130824    94  75  0   0
14939   20130825    96  73  0   0
14939   20130826    97  75  0   0
14939   20130827    98  72  0   0
14939   20130828    95  67  0   0
14939   20130829    98  68  0   0
14939   20130830    100 70  0   0
14939   20130831    96  72  0   0
14939   20120801    100 72  0   0
14939   20120802    96  70  0   0.11
14939   20120803    99  69  0   0
14939   20120804    84  59  0   0
14939   20120805    89  55  0   0
14939   20120806    97  60  0   0
14939   20120807    102 69  0   0
14939   20120808    103 67  0   0
14939   20120809    87  65  0   0
14939   20120810    82  55  0   0
14939   20120811    83  51  0   0.01
14939   20120812    84  63  0   0
14939   20120813    80  57  0   0
14939   20120814    87  57  0   0
14939   20120815    94  58  0   0
14939   20120816    77  49  0   0
14939   20120817    82  44  0   0
14939   20120818    78  45  0   0
14939   20120819    83  46  0   0
14939   20120820    89  48  0   0
14939   20120821    94  53  0   0
14939   20120822    93  58  0   0
14939   20120823    93  66  0   0
14939   20120824    77  68  0   0.13
14939   20120825    76  65  0   0.05
14939   20120826    85  62  0   0
14939   20120827    93  57  0   0
14939   20120828    97  60  0   0
14939   20120829    98  63  0   0
14939   20120830    100 66  0   0
14939   20120831    99  58  0   0
14939   20110801    104 75  0   0
14939   20110802    95  76  0   0
14939   20110803    89  69  0   0
14939   20110804    86  71  0   0.13
14939   20110805    85  71  0   0.45
14939   20110806    92  67  0   0.57
14939   20110807    88  68  0   0.02
14939   20110808    87  66  0   0.13
14939   20110809    84  63  0   0
14939   20110810    80  62  0   0
14939   20110811    85  56  0   1.06
14939   20110812    84  62  0   0.56
14939   20110813    83  62  0   0
14939   20110814    83  57  0   0
14939   20110815    79  65  0   0.64
14939   20110816    77  67  0   0
14939   20110817    85  65  0   0
14939   20110818    90  65  0   0.66
14939   20110819    84  63  0   0.05
14939   20110820    80  66  0   0
14939   20110821    85  61  0   0
14939   20110822    88  71  0   0
14939   20110823    95  76  0   0
14939   20110824    87  59  0   0
14939   20110825    84  55  0   0
14939   20110826    87  62  0   0
14939   20110827    86  61  0   0
14939   20110828    81  64  0   0
14939   20110829    82  57  0   0
14939   20110830    84  65  0   2.62
14939   20110831    92  66  0   0
14939   20100801    90  64  0   0
14939   20100802    94  74  0   0
14939   20100803    91  73  0   0
14939   20100804    88  70  0   0.44
14939   20100805    87  66  0   0
14939   20100806    87  66  0   0
14939   20100807    92  68  0   0
14939   20100808    98  75  0   0
14939   20100809    95  72  0   0
14939   20100810    96  74  0   0
14939   20100811    99  69  0   0
14939   20100812    100 67  0   0
14939   20100813    95  70  0   0.02
14939   20100814    92  63  0   0
14939   20100815    86  57  0   0
14939   20100816    90  59  0   0.27
14939   20100817    69  64  0   0.18
14939   20100818    84  65  0   0
14939   20100819    95  65  0   0
14939   20100820    89  72  0   0.09
14939   20100821    95  67  0   0
14939   20100822    94  64  0   0
14939   20100823    94  66  0   0.27
14939   20100824    81  56  0   0.7
14939   20100825    85  52  0   0
14939   20100826    87  57  0   0
14939   20100827    87  54  0   0
14939   20100828    91  58  0   0
14939   20100829    93  63  0   0
14939   20100830    94  73  0   0
14939   20100831    94  68  0   0.84
14939   20090801    78  58  0   0
14939   20090802    94  54  0   0
14939   20090803    94  65  0   0
14939   20090804    88  66  0   0.07
14939   20090805    85  63  0   0.04
14939   20090806    84  59  0   0
14939   20090807    97  73  0   0.04
14939   20090808    102 76  0   0
14939   20090809    83  66  0   0.11
14939   20090810    88  59  0   0
14939   20090811    89  57  0   0
14939   20090812    96  66  0   0
14939   20090813    93  65  0   0
14939   20090814    93  62  0   0
14939   20090815    84  67  0   0.95
14939   20090816    81  63  0   0.6
14939   20090817    83  57  0   0
14939   20090818    84  58  0   0
14939   20090819    83  66  0   0.33
14939   20090820    77  59  0   0
14939   20090821    74  53  0   0
14939   20090822    79  48  0   0
14939   20090823    83  55  0   0
14939   20090824    91  63  0   0
14939   20090825    86  70  0   0
14939   20090826    77  66  0   1.06
14939   20090827    78  58  0   0
14939   20090828    78  52  0   0
14939   20090829    72  51  0   0
14939   20090830    71  48  0   0
14939   20090831    73  42  0   0
14939   20080801    93  71  0   0
14939   20080802    99  73  0   0
14939   20080803    102 70  0   0
14939   20080804    93  75  0   0
14939   20080805    85  65  0   0
14939   20080806    86  63  0   0
14939   20080807    90  60  0   0
14939   20080808    90  61  0   0
14939   20080809    81  66  0   0.24
14939   20080810    88  59  0   0.26
14939   20080811    84  65  0   0.4
14939   20080812    87  63  0   0.02
14939   20080813    91  65  0   0
14939   20080814    86  66  0   0
14939   20080815    84  62  0   0
14939   20080816    84  58  0   0
14939   20080817    86  55  0   0
14939   20080818    89  60  0   0
14939   20080819    88  60  0   0
14939   20080820    87  57  0   0
14939   20080821    84  66  0   0
14939   20080822    95  70  0   0
14939   20080823    83  63  0   0
14939   20080824    83  61  0   0.46
14939   20080825    83  56  0   0
14939   20080826    82  59  0   0
14939   20080827    87  64  0   0.4
14939   20080828    90  57  0   0
14939   20080829    89  50  0   0
14939   20080830    91  54  0   0
14939   20080831    93  69  0   0
14939   20070801    89  68  0   0.28
14939   20070802    90  66  0   0
14939   20070803    90  67  0   0.16
14939   20070804    96  76  0   0
14939   20070805    92  74  0   0
14939   20070806    93  73  0   0.21
14939   20070807    85  72  0   0.44
14939   20070808    90  72  0   1.34
14939   20070809    96  74  0   0
14939   20070810    96  67  0   0.46
14939   20070811    97  72  0   0
14939   20070812    95  72  0   0.12
14939   20070813    100 70  0   0
14939   20070814    98  75  0   0
14939   20070815    92  71  0   0
14939   20070816    83  72  0   0.11
14939   20070817    85  71  0   0.1
14939   20070818    93  73  0   0
14939   20070819    91  73  0   0
14939   20070820    96  70  0   0.39
14939   20070821    95  70  0   0
14939   20070822    88  67  0   0.96
14939   20070823    86  67  0   0.55
14939   20070824    75  63  0   0.01
14939   20070825    81  58  0   0
14939   20070826    89  68  0   0
14939   20070827    95  75  0   0
14939   20070828    94  67  0   0.65
14939   20070829    76  62  0   0.02
14939   20070830    80  57  0   0
14939   20070831    83  56  0   0
14939   20060801    105 79  0   0
14939   20060802    85  65  0   0
14939   20060803    90  58  0   0
14939   20060804    91  54  0   0
14939   20060805    102 70  0   0.1
14939   20060806    91  72  0   0.4
14939   20060807    82  67  0   0.09
14939   20060808    86  66  0   1.71
14939   20060809    100 74  0   0
14939   20060810    90  74  0   0.04
14939   20060811    91  69  0   0
14939   20060812    90  70  0   0
14939   20060813    82  71  0   0.11
14939   20060814    83  58  0   0
14939   20060815    85  53  0   0
14939   20060816    87  64  0   0.49
14939   20060817    90  70  0   0.14
14939   20060818    88  69  0   0.6
14939   20060819    78  61  0   0.09
14939   20060820    81  57  0   0
14939   20060821    89  60  0   0
14939   20060822    87  63  0   0
14939   20060823    91  63  0   0
14939   20060824    95  68  0   0
14939   20060825    83  68  0   0.02
14939   20060826    80  63  0   0
14939   20060827    76  62  0   0.26
14939   20060828    67  63  0   0
14939   20060829    80  59  0   0
14939   20060830    82  52  0   0
14939   20060831    83  60  0   0
```

This is my output:

```
Name: John Fischer    
Hometown:  Denver, Colorado
Birthdate:  3 February 1980
Location: Chicago
Date           AvgTemp  MaxTemp  MinTemp  AvgSnow  MaxSnow  MinSnow  AvgPrec  MaxPrec  MinPrec
```

Comment: Fixed some English.  I actually don't see much wrong with the question.  You have the code, the expected result, the actual result and the data all there.

Answer (score 0):

Turn this:

```
if(prec[i] < minPr15 ) { 
            minPr15 = prec[i];
```

into this:

```
if(prec[i] <= minPr15 ) { 
            minPr15 = prec[i];
```

And it will print.  Figure out what's wrong with the rest of your calculations.  Also, just isolate the first year(2015) and get that right.